# Flatten dataframe with nested struct ArrayType using pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with this schema

```
root
  |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
  |-- Books: array (nullable = false)
  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
  |    |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer (nullable = false)
  |    |    |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true) 
  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
```

How to flat all columns into one level with Pyspark ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) function:

```
df2 = (df.selectExpr("AUTHOR_ID", "NAME", "inline(Books)")
       .selectExpr("*", "inline(Chapters)")
       .drop("Chapters")
       )
```

Or [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = (df.withColumn("Books", F.explode("Books"))
       .select("*", "Books.*")
       .withColumn("Chapters", F.explode("Chapters"))
       .select("*", "Chapters.*")
       )
```

Comment: how to  do the reverse work ? i.e after flatten we take back the first dataframe, how is it possible with pyspark ?

Comment: or maybe just doing some 'groupby' and aggregations as usual

Comment: @Smaillns yes, you first group by `AUTHOR_ID` + `NAME` + `BOOK_ID` to create the array of chapters, then group by `AUTHOR_ID` + `NAME` to create the array of books.