# what's the easiest way to explode/flatten deeply nested struct using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have an example dataset:

```
+---+------------------------------+
|id |example_field                  |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |{[{[{111, AAA}, {222, BBB}]}]}|
+---+------------------------------+
```

The data type of the two fields are:

```
[('id', 'int'),
 ('example_field',
  'struct<xxx:array<struct<nested_field:array<struct<field_1:int,field_2:string>>>>>')]
```

My question is if there's a way/function to flatten the field `example_field` using pyspark?

my expected output is something like this:

```
id  field_1 field_2
1   111     AAA
1   222     BBB
```

Comment: can you share the code for creating the example dataset?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten dataframe with nested struct ArrayType using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71284667/flatten-dataframe-with-nested-struct-arraytype-using-pyspark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(
    df
    .withColumn('_temp_ef', F.explode('example_field.xxx'))
    .withColumn('_temp_nf', F.explode('_temp_ef.nested_field'))
    .select(
        'id',
        F.col('_temp_nf.*')
    )
)
```

The function [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) creates a row for each element in an array, while `select` turns the fields of `nested_field` structure into columns.

The result is:

```bash
+---+-------+-------+
|id |field_1|field_2|
+---+-------+-------+
|1  |111    |AAA    |
|1  |222    |BBB    |
+---+-------+-------+
```

*Note: I assumed that your DataFrame is something like this:*

```bash
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- example_field: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- xxx: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- nested_field: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- field_2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hi @PieCot what if I want to remove the field `nested_field` but remain the rest of the structure the same?

Comment: Hi, excuse me but I do not understand: do you want a different output dataframe than the one in the question? If so, can you please provide an example?